# NUL in Apache2 error's log

Tags: logging, apache2

On my server is Debian 9 with Apache2, and quite often apache2 just stop working and I have to log into SSH and manually start it.

So I looked into Apache2 error's log and I found lot of **NUL**s, like on this screenshot:

[image]

So I really don't know what to do, because I don't know why apache2 crashed.
I don't think it is because of warning in

> /srv/Cyclone3/.core/.libs/TOM/Warning.pm

because I have quite often these warnings and no problem with it (I know I have to fix it in future, but I have to solve this Apache2 crash now).

Comment: I think it is related to apache2 configuration. You can see live above null.